# why the checkall code doesn't work?

Tags: jquery

html code:

```
<div>

        <input type="checkbox" onclick="selectAll(this);" />select all<br/>
        <input type="checkbox"  /><br/>
        <input type="checkbox"  /><br/>
        <input type="checkbox"  /><br/>
        <input type="checkbox"  /><br/>
        <input type="checkbox"  /><br/>
        <input type="checkbox"  /><br/>
</div>
```

jquery code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  function selectAll(checkbox){
    alert("test");
    $("input[type=checkbox]").attr('checked',$(checkbox).attr('checked'));
    }
    });
```

why the select and unselect all doesn't work. when i put the alert statement to test what's wrong with the code. the alert also doesn't work.

**i want to know why my code doesn't work?**

Comment: Where is your `selectAll` method?

Comment: Where did you define selectAll function? What is the value of checkbox parameter in the `$(document).ready(function(checkbox){...});`?

Comment: i am sorry. i missed the method. i have updated my OP. thank you.

Comment: Move the 'function selectAll(checkbox)' out of '$(document).ready(function(){......'

Comment: Monday,why i should move the functon out of $(document).ready().could it be that can't put the defined function in it?

Comment: @runeveryday, just a question of sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't make much sense. What you're currently doing is passing an event handler to the ready method that checks all the inputs on document ready. And this will happen only if you fix the typo.

What you need is something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/NJuqm/

```
//Should be inside $(document).ready()
$('#sel_all').click(function(){
    if (this.checked) {
        $('input:checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked');
    } else {
        $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
    }
});

    <input type="checkbox" id='sel_all'/>select all<br/>
    <input type="checkbox"  /><br/>
    <input type="checkbox"  /><br/>
    <input type="checkbox"  /><br/>
    <input type="checkbox"  /><br/>
    <input type="checkbox"  /><br/>
    <input type="checkbox"  /><br/>
```

Comment: if i want to put the function that i defined into $(document).ready how should i do? thank you.

Comment: @runeveryday not much actually. Just move it out of the document.ready handler. Here's a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/crD66/

Answer (score 2):

**Easiest “check all” ever with jQuery**

HTML:

```
<div>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkall" />select all<br/>
        <input type="checkbox"  /><br/>
        <input type="checkbox"  /><br/>
        <input type="checkbox"  /><br/>
        <input type="checkbox"  /><br/>
        <input type="checkbox"  /><br/>
        <input type="checkbox"  /><br/>
</div>
```

jQuery：

```
$(function () {
    $('.checkall').click(function () {
        $(this).parents('div').find(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
    });
});
```

Comment: Move the 'function selectAll(checkbox)' out of '$(document).ready(function(){......'

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You have an extra quote         `$("input[type=checkbox]").attr('checked',**'**$(checkbox).attr('checked'));`</strike>

<strike>And misspelled alert</strike>

<strike>And there is no checkbox variable</strike>

<strike>And i dont see no selectAll function</strike>  (you can drop this inline stuff)

```
<div>

        <input type="checkbox" class="checkall" />select all<br/>
        <input type="checkbox"  /><br/>
        <input type="checkbox"  /><br/>
        <input type="checkbox"  /><br/>
        <input type="checkbox"  /><br/>
        <input type="checkbox"  /><br/>
        <input type="checkbox"  /><br/>
</div>

$('.checkall').change(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', $(this).attr('checked'));
});
```

And you're missing mandatory quotes after the equal sign

Basically there is lots wrong with your code. :)

**EDIT**

OP completely changed his code in question :P

Answer (score 1):

`$(document).ready` fires when the document has loaded. It is not a named function.

Your HTML assumes there is a function named `selectAll`.

try swapping your `$(document).ready` with the following.

```
function selectAll(checkbox)
{
    alert("test");
    $("input[type=checkbox]").attr('checked',$(checkbox).attr('checked'));
}
```

**UPDATE**

Defining a function does not execute the function. So the definition does not need to be inside your `$(document).ready`. It will only be called when the first checkbox is clicked.

Comment: if i want to put the function into $(document).ready how should i do?

Comment: because there are some parts i used the $(document).ready ,in order to make the code tidy, i want to put the functon in it.

Comment: @runeveryday what parts did you use in `$(document).ready`? How does it make your code tidier?

Comment: in my js file, i used $(document).ready(function(){   }). could i put the functon selectAll(checkbox) into it.

Comment: @reuneveryday Defining your method separately is perfectly normal and "clean".